# Dataframe from pickled file seems impossible to be read in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

If I run

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_pickle('test.pkl.gz')
len(df)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

If I try `df.head()`, I get:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

If I try `df.shape`, I get:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

`sys.getsizeof(df)` throws:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_data'
```

but the original file size should be 10.5MB

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask

Comment: I suspect either the file is corrupted or has been created with a different version of python

Comment: @manu190466 you are most likely right, I'll try to generate a new file and try again